# Is there a way to show a banner when you change directory on vsftpd?

Tags: vsftpd

I have a vsftpd instance running on my Ubuntu Server. I need to show a banner when users change into a specific directory ie:

```
ftp> cd /cars
>>> These cars are for lease
```

Is there any way to do this? I know how to set banners for the whole server, but not sure how to do it for a single directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, using the `dirmessage_enabled` directive, which reads a `.message` file from the directory you change into.